# Using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper without homebrew's Python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, homebrew

I use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to manage most of my software installs, but I find it complicated to use Python, especially virtualenv (and virtualenvwrapper) to manage package in an isolated way. The problem is that I found that virtualenv symlinks python to the current version of Python installed via Homebrew, like this:

```
~/.pip/virtualenvs/httpie
├── include
│   └── python2.7 -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.7_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
└── lib
    └── python2.7
        ├── UserDict.py -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.7_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
        ├── UserDict.pyc
        ├── _abcoll.py -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.7_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
        ├── _abcoll.pyc
        ├── _weakrefset.py -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.7_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
        ├── _weakrefset.pyc
        ├── abc.py -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.7_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.py
        ├── abc.pyc
        ├── codecs.py -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.7_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
        ├── codecs.pyc
[...]
```

This causes all sorts of problems of linkage whenever there's an update to Python via homebrew:

```
$ http --head http://flic.kr/p/dQm85A
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/3dweb/.pip/virtualenvs/httpie/bin/python2.7
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

**How can I setup virtualenv to ALWAYS (automatically) point to the system Python whenever i create a new virtualenv?**

Comment: An alternative to using your system Python is to use the option `--always-copy` with `mkvirtualenv`. This will copy your Python binaries instead of symlinking, which may resolve your issues with updating the Homebrew Python.

Comment: Yep, that worked good! I did notice it in the --help page of mkvirtualenv and thought it would be ok, but decided to ask first. Of course, if you don't mind ~20MB of copied binaries and libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install virtualenv into the system Python via pip outside of homebrew. Invoke that virtualenv directly.

Comment: This is correct -- `mkvirtualenv` has the help text "The default is the interpreter that virtualenv was installed with".

Comment: I tried to, but I had issues:
````/usr/bin/easy_install pip````
First of all, I had to change ownership of this directory:
````/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages````
Then, when I run the install command again, I saw that this happened:

````Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin````
````Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin````
````Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin````
````Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg````
And this worries me: will homebrew replace it?

Comment: No need to change permissions, that is what ``sudo`` is for. You are installing into the core system so you need root perms.

Comment: I honestly do not know about homebrew and the pip in ``/usr/local/bin`` interacting. My suggestion is to rename ``/usr/local/bin/pip`` to ``/usr/local/bin/pip-system``. This way you know you have run the right program just by the name. Then you do not need to worry about $PATH issues.

Comment: Thanks, I follow some of your suggestions…
In short, I uninstalled Python via homebrew, then I installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper via easy_install, even though I could install pip and install those via that.
Anyway, once done, I installed Python via homebrew again. Now, whenever I create a new virtualenv, it points to the system once, since as @HuuNguyen said, it points to the one that it was installed with.
Probably it could be improved, but for now I'm satisfied!